# Jacoco shows that class declaration is not covered

Tags: java, junit, junit4, jacoco

I am writing test for my application. I have installed jacoco plugin for my gradle project. After making test coverage report I see "public class MyClass" in red color, that means, that it is not covered.

So, how can I fix this and make it covered(colored with green)?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Just do not use @PrepareForTest for this class int tests